# How to remove outliers from a dataset using bivariate boxplot

Tags: r, dataset, boxplot, outliers

I have a data-set (See below) that is made up of multiple variables, two of these are 'manu' and 'popul' and they both contain numeric values.

[image]

From this data I plotted a bivariate boxplot using 'manu' and 'popul' so that I could find outliers between these two variables. This is what it looks like:

[image]

Then from this plot I can see there are a few outliers, I was able to identify what values are outliers using the code below, I will also show which values are outliers:

[image]

[image]

What I would like to know is how do I now take the row that contains these values and remove them from the dataset?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the desired subset like so:

[image]

Comment: Don't know how I didn't think of this, I literally used almost the same code already. Thanks for the help